# Android canvas drawText right to left

Tags: android, canvas

I have an app that handels Arabic too, but my Arabic users have a problem that the drawText flip the word .. Arabic must be from right to left. How do I make the canvas drawText from right to left?

[image]

See in the picture the highlighted text is the right text its a textView and it's fine. But the canvas DrawText the one in a circle is wrong. It must be from right to left, how do I make the canvas drawText from right to left?

My drawText code:

```
 c.drawText(txt, (float) (c.getWidth()/2.7), (float) (c.getHeight()/2 + paint.getTextSize()/1.5), paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Bidi class to preprocess your text:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html